# why summary( a_categorical_var) does not show "NA" counts?

Tags: r, summary

I want to examine my dataset - flights, and use `summary()` function.

```r
summary(flights["tailnum"])
```

Results:

```r
   tailnum         
 Length:336776     
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character
```

In particular, it does **not** show that the character variable `tailnum` has any NAs.

However, when I use `sum(is.na(flights$tailnum))`, it shows it has NAs.

```r
[1] 2512
```

What is the best function to examine a categorical variable - show its levels, missing values, total number of rows and frequencies for each level?

Comment: If you look at the source of `summary.default` (which is used by `summary.data.frame`), it specifically looks for `NA`s in numeric data and does not look for them in other classes. This is inconsistent. Have you considered writing your own function as a near-duplicate of `summary` so that you can get that added to the output?

Comment: This does seem inconsistent (and may be worth discussing on `r-devel`. I'd imagine that some of the reason is that character vectors are almost never used in statistical analyses without first (sometimes implicitly) converting them to factors ...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `summary()` method for *character* variables doesn't report NAs. (This does seem a bit inconsistent, might be worth reporting/discussing on the `r-devel@r-project.org` mailing list ...)

If you convert the variable to a factor and apply `summary()` to it specifically you'll get a table of the counts of the first 98 levels (followed by an "Other" category and the number of NAs).

```r
summary(factor(flights$tailnum))
```

If you really want a full tabulation:

```r
tt <- table(flights$tailnum, useNA = "ifany")
print(tt)
```

Although `length(tt)` is 4044, telling you that there are 4043 distinct non-NA values (+ `NA` values): `head(table(tt))` and `tail(table(tt))` tell you that there are hundreds of values that occur only a few times, and a few values that occur hundreds (or thousands) of times.

If you're using tidyverse and want to convert *all* character variables to factors:

```r
flights %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), factor))
```